# loop thru offset data copy to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

from the first pic how do you loop thru the offset data then copy to another sheet result is second pic

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted.

```
Sub getemail()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Ws_Pic1 As Object, Ws_Pic2 As Object
    
    'Ws_Pic1 --> original data
    'Ws_Pic2 --> result
    
    Set Ws_Pic1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Ws_Pic2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1 (2)")

    For i = 1 To Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Value2 <> "" Then
            If Ws_Pic2.Range("F1").Value2 = "" Then
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("A1").Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F1").Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F1").Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F1").Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F1").Offset(0, 3).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 3).Value2
                Else
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value2
                    Ws_Pic2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value2 = Ws_Pic1.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 3).Value2
            End If
        End If
    Next i
       
End Sub
```

Comment: edited the remove rows. should work now.

Comment: hi, i actually need it in another sheet and there is existing data in columns B to E in the result sheet

Comment: try it again, just edited my answer. But I must caution you, if I didn't guess wrongly. you are trying to splice 2 data together. Not sure if this will mess up anything, you don't have to worry if column B-E is Excel formula, but if it is not formula you have to see if data make sense

Also remember to change your worksheet name.